# Dorsal root fibres

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, neurology, peripheral-nervous-system

How can dorsal root fibres be unmylinated though are responsible for conduction of pain and temperature? How is their conduction so fast without even being myelinated? Is presence of only one axon( indicating that a single axon travels from skin to dorsal root ganglion) enough for such fast conduction?